# mysql linked list sort query, why is it working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linked-list

My table looks like this:

```
+------------------------+
| id | title  | position |
+------------------------+
|  1 | test 2 |        3 |
+------------------------+
|  2 | test 3 |        1 |
+------------------------+
|  3 | test 1 |        0 |
+------------------------+
```

I found this query which retrieves the rows ordered based on the position field which holds the id of the predecessor.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    mytable AS t2
ON t2.position = t1.id
```

I wonder why this is working because there is no order by clause and the database should't know that position 0 is the row to start at.

Comment: *"why is it working?"* --- Now there's a twist. People mostly come here asking the complete opposite.

Comment: The order the rows are returned is _NOT_ guaranteed if there isn't an `ORDER BY` clause on the query. MySQL is free to return the rows in any order it chooses. The repeatable behavior you observe is due to the query execution plan that MySQL happens to be using; if MySQL is using an index, the rows _may_ be returned in the sequence they appear in the index. If MySQL is performing a scan of a table, the rows _may_ be returned in the order they appear in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is dependent on the order you inserted the rows into the table. If, for example, you had inserted the row with id=3 before you inserted the row with id=2, then you would have got a non-sorted result.

As it stands, you are pulling the data out of t1 in the order of `id` because that is the order you put the elements into the table

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63a925/2 and try it for yourself.

N.B. Databases are not **guaranteed** to work as you state, it is simply that most databases work this way. You should **not** rely on this behaviour as a minor change to the schema or query could ruin your whole day! Note also that if `id` is a (primary?) key, the insert order will probably be overridden by the fact that the database will pull the rows out in the order of the index.

Comment: +1. The sequence the rows are returned is definitely _NOT_ guaranteed, without an `ORDER BY` clause. Absent an `ORDER BY` clause on the query, the database is free to return the rows in _any_ order.

Comment: @spencer7593  Thank you - I've also expanded my answer to include keys which may also change the order...

Answer (score 0):

That query is joining in table 2 based on the ID in table 1 equaling the position in table 2. Since the IDs in table 1 are sequential, the output appears to be sorted